# Install Composer MacOS Sierra

Tags: macos, mac

so I'm trying to install composer ([getcomposer.org/](http://getcomposer.org/)) from my Macbook, I noticed it's a bit different from Windows. I ran the commands specified in the page and it installed in `/Users/macbookpro/composer.phar`, however in windows I can call the `composer` commands from anywhere in my directories, on my mac I can't and to get the command to work I have to type in `php composer.phar`inside the directory it was installed in.

So my question is: how can I call my `composer` command from anywhere in my directories? I want to be able to run, for example, `composer install` and not `php composer.phar install`. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented on the composer [website](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-linux-unix-osx) you need to copy the executable into your bin folder. For example, from your installation directory, execute this:

`cp composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer`

That will copy and rename the `composer.phar` executable as `composer` into `/usr/local/bin`, which is a directory that is on your "PATH" by default. Because it's on your PATH, you can execute it from anywhere. After the copy, try executing `composer`. If it doesn't work, check the execute permissions of `/usr/local/bin/composer`. Set it executable like so:

`chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/composer`